# Nothing comes to Sink defined in alsoTo

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

alsoTo doesn't seem to be working for me. Items don't come to sink defined in it. Here is what I have.

```
val merged: Source[ArticleWithKeywords, _] =  ...
val (ks, fut) = merged
  .alsoTo(Flow[ArticleWithKeywords].map { a => a.id -> a.ids.toList }.to(queueManager.getIdsForAnsSink))
  .map(_.id)
  .groupedWithin(100, 5 seconds)
  .mapAsync(4) { ids => runReferenceFetching(ids) }
  .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
  .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
  .run()
```

But I see items reaching runReferenceFetching. What am I missing ?

Comment: If you replace your `queueManager.getIdsForAnsSink` with `Sink.foreach`, does it still not work as expected? (or if that does fix it, is there something not wrong/unexpected with that sink)

Comment: @johanandren It does work with `Sink.foreach`. But on the other hand simple `Sourse(List(..)).runWith(queueManager.getIdsForAnsSink) also works. So I'm confused at what's at fault here.

Comment: alsoTo is actually the broadcast stage which backpressures if either downstream branch backpressures, so I would say the elements do reach that sink but then gets lost somehow. Concurrency issue perhaps?

Comment: @johanandren Found the bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out problem has nothing to do with `alsoTo`. Problem was with sink which was created using `Source.fromPublisher`. I erroneously thought I can create multiple sinks using same `Publisher[T]`. Since there was already another sink second one didn't work.